# Can I return values with execute() or executeUpdate()?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a server with connection to a database in postgreSQL and I want to return the ID of a new row to the client once it is inserted.
I've tried this:

```
int id = stmt.execute("insert into [table] values(default,0) returning id;");
```

the SQL statement works if I'm working directly on the database but not here, I get this error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.

I'm thinking its because execute() and executeUpdate() aren't supposed to return values so I added this:

```
stmt.execute("insert into [table] values(default,0) returning id;");
ResultSet id = stmt.executeQuery("select last_insert_id();");
```

Apparently that statement is for mySQL so it doesn't work, I've read that CURRVAL and NEXTVAL do this in postgreSQL but I haven't been able to do it and I've also read it's not always acurate.

Is there something I'm missing or another way to do it?

Comment: On PostgreSQL `insert into table` with `returning` statement - this is equivalent to any select statement. Try it: `stmt.executeQuery("insert into [table] values(default,0) returning id;")`

Comment: now I'm getting this: ```java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet ``` any idea what's wrong? I'm using ResultSet to send data to the client in other places in the code and it's wokring fine

Comment: @AldieYung You can't serialize a result set. If you need to serialize things, you need to get the values from the result set and pack them in a way that can be serialized. That said, you really shouldn't use Java serialization unless you really, really have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getGeneratedKeys()`

```java
String sql = "insert into the_table(some_column) values (?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id"});    
pstmt.setInt(1, 0);
int numRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
int newId = -1;
if (keys.next()) {
  newId = keys.getInt(1);
}
```

Alternatively you can also use:

```java
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("...", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

This also works with batchedStatements (after `pstmt.executeBatch()`)  or multi-row inserts. In that case the `if (keys.next())` must be changed to a `while()` loop to iterate over all generated IDs